# Как убрать желтое выделение после автозаполнения Android?

Tags: android

В моем android приложении есть [окно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyhQp.jpg) авторизации с двумя полями ввода.
По нажатию на кнопку, на оба инпута [накладывается серый foreground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTVRx.jpg). Все работает как часы, но при использовании сервиса автозаполнения (предоставляемого андроидом), в моем случае это NordPass, поля ввода [выделяются желтым](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZI8s.jpg), да еще и [без закругления](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQkLt.jpg)!

Выделение сбрасывается с инпута, если изменить в нем текст (суть в самом ивенте редактирования текста).
По нажатию на кнопку, мой foreground [накладывается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcdIM.jpg) на это выделение.
В моих values цветах такого желтого цвета нет.

Кто-то может подсказать, как убрать или отредактировать это выделение?

Comment: Кажется можно в стилях прописать прозрачный фон автозаполнения через атрибут `android:autofilledHighlight`. [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627129/android-how-to-remove-edittexts-highlightcolor)

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо!